# Minimum x and y coordinate of 2d array. Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a `nx2` array where the first column represents x-coordinates and the second column y-coordinates, for example:

```
array = np.array([0,3],
                 [1,5],
                 [2,1],
                 [3,2])
```

How can I obtain the minimum y-coordinate with the corresponding x-coordinate returned allong with it? In the example, I want `[1,2]` returned, where 2 is the row index, not the numerical value contained in the array, but 1 is the actual numerical value.

I know I can simply use `np.amin(array[:,1])` to obtain the minimum y-coordinate, but this doesn't give me any info of what x-coordinate corresponds to the y-minimum.

I have looked at the documentation of [np.amin](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.amin.html#numpy.amin) to see if it can return two parameters but it does not look like it can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array[np.argmin(array[:,1])][0]
```

You want to reference array values like this in a 2d array.

```
array[column][row]
```

np.argmin will give you the smallest number's index in the column and array*[0] will give the first element in the row

Comment: Thanks, argmin is indeed the function I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this:

```
>>> index = array[:, 1].argmin()
>>> np.unravel_index((index * 2) + 1, array.shape)
(2, 1)
# reverse to get the column index first.
>>> np.unravel_index((index * 2) + 1, array.shape)[::-1]
(1, 2)
```